# Why do HtmlHelpers need an argument to this HtmlHelper helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why do HtmlHelpers need to be declared with an argument to an HtmlHelper helper?

i.e

```
public static string ScheduleEntries(this HtmlHelper helper, ...)
```

I've never noticed that syntax before in C#, what is it called?

Thanks

-Matt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

The way it works for MVC is that `Html` in the view is a property of HtmlHelper type on the ViewPage class.